# Whatsapp linking

Tags: android, html, ios, whatsapp

Im currently working on a website for a client and am having some trouble getting a whatsapp link working on an Iphone. There is a button that should be redirecting the user to a whatsapp number, and it is doing to on my pc, but when I take it to my iphone suddenly it no longer works. Any ideas on what is happening?

```
<a id="app" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/0896168600?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20man%20with%20a%20van"> <div class="whatsapp">
                <div class="left">
                <p>Contact on WhatsApp</p>
                <p>089 61 68 600</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <img src="/WhatsApp.svg.png" alt="">
            </div>
            </div>
</a>
```

Here are some images of the problem in action aswell as the link to the website and the whatsapp documentation used to write the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW5nW.png
https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=en
https://fiverrtestsite.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this for mobile**

*So for a danish number +45 1234 5678 it would be*
**4512345678**
Change 45 to your contry code

```html
<a id="app" target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?phone=4512345678"> </a>
```

OR

```html
<a id="app" target="_blank" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=4512345678"> </a>
```

This will only work for mobile, not for desktop. You shuld make a modal so when its clicked they can choose to open mobile or desktop version of the link.